# Enabling USB access on HP Terminal client

Tags: terminal-server, usb-flash-drive

I have an HP terminal client (t5550 Thin) connected via network to an ubuntu server. However, the terminal doesn't seem to support USB access to the server (as simple way to upload files, for example). How can I enable usb support? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are using LTSP, you should check out edubuntu's wiki page on [how to enable local devices in LTSP](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/EnableLTSP5LocalDevices).

But be aware that there are still some issues with 64-bit server.